# Multiple shadows in box-shadow for elevated elements in Material Design

Tags: css, material-design

I was looking at the code of some material-design based frameworks and I see that the implemented buttons are often "casting" two shadows in CSS. Here's an example of css declaration:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px;
```

So these are two shadows positioned in exactly the same place, one has a blur of 6px and the next one is 4px. I understand what this code does, but I don't understand the motivation to put two shadows on exactly the same coordinates.

Please help to understand this visual effect better.

Example of component: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two shadows are blending together to achieve sharper or custom-shaped gradient from element edge to the end of shadow - effect you often can't achieve with single shadow. In the example below, resulted shadows are different:

```css
#single {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

#multiple {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="single"></div>
<div id="multiple"></div>
```